# Play framework: Unable to Inject Database object

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework

I am trying to connect to mysql using play framework. I am new to play and unable to figure out the exact problem. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

The configuration in `conf\application.conf` is as follows:

```
  config = "db"
  default = "default"
  db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/ng_play"
  db.default.username=root
  db.default.password="****"
  ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

build.sbt

```
name := """play-scala-tutorial-one"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Comment: `db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ng_play"` you forgot the port

Comment: already tried by providing the port but the output is same.

Comment: which play version?

Comment: `db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT TRUE"`  add this to `application.conf` and try again

Comment: Didn't work out, same output.

`config = "db"
  default = "default"
  db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/ng_play"
  db.default.username=root
  db.default.password="root"
  ebean.default = ["models.*"]
  db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT TRUE"`

Comment: post your build.sbt

Comment: build.sbt added in the description.

Comment: Is there some problem with build.sbt config?

Comment: @SumitAgarwal remove the "config = "db" / default = "default" part. If you still have a problem post the full stacktrace (from the console)

Answer (score 0):

Mysql version and database-connector version was mismatch. and also adding `db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT TRUE"` this to `application.conf` helped to mitigate one issue.

Thanks @silentprogrammer and @salem for help.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark this as the accepted answer.